# check if default app for extensions exists

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is there a possibilty in Windows phone, to check if there is an default app installed for a specific Extension?

Lets say I have a `*.html`-file on skydrive. And my app can't register for the `*.html` extension, because I can only register for 20 file extensions, and others are more important to me.

I could open this file within my app, but I would prefer to let the user choose, if he wants to open it with my app, or with another one. But if there is no other app installed, I want to open it directly with my app.

So I have to check if there are default apps installed for a specific file-Extension. Can I do this on Windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

With the Uri schemes in Windows Phone 8, it's not possible to check if a Uri is already being used or what app is using it. As [the official documentation mentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Howassociationworksfortheuser), your app simply registers the Uri then it's up to the user to make the decision...

> When the user launches a file or URI from an app, what happens next
> depends on which apps are installed on the phone. If no apps on the
> phone can handle that particular file or URI association, the user
> will be given the option to get one that does.
>
> When there is only one app on the phone registered for a particular
> file or URI association, that app will be automatically launched when
> the user wants to open it. If a user has more than one app on their
> phone registered for a file or URI association, each time the user
> opens the file, they will be as asked which app they want to use.

Be aware, there is [a list of reserved system Uris](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that cannot be used. If you add them to your app, the system will ignore them.

Uri schemes are **not** available in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Yeah... this is the official view. I knew this already, but I thought there might be a hacky way to look if an app is installed, which registered for a specific Extension...

Comment: I'm afraid there are no tricks or ways around this limitation - when you try to invoke an app via Uri schemes, you have no idea or control over what happens next (same on Windows 8)